# How to make a for loop for a json file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to get a JSON array of objects with a for loop but for some reason it only works if I pass the index explicitly as a number (e.g. `parseJSON.sites[0]`). If I use a variable, which I would prefer in this example because of the loop, the shown example doesn't work.

```js
let openJSON = fs.readFileSync('./pages/jsons/main.json', 'utf-8');
let parseJSON = JSON.parse(openJSON);
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    //this code doens't work and return: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined          
    main.push(parseJSON.sites[i]["name"]);

    //this code works, and returns what i expected
    main.push(parseJSON.sites[0]["name"]);
}


//main.json
{
    "sites": [
        { "name": "stackoverflow", "url": "stackoverflow.com" },
        { "name": "Youtube", "url": "www.youtube.com" },
    ]
}
```

I have no idea why this code doesn't work. I already tried to change the name of the variable `i`, in case of any conflict but it still returns the same error. I also tried to execute the code snippet without the `.push()` method.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Fragments of code that throw syntax errors when you try to run them don't really help anyone solve your problem.

Comment: Bellow the for loop is my json file (i forget to comment that)

Comment: @quentin the function is the for loop and opening and parsing json, in this case the max i could add is this: let openJSON = fs.readFileSync('./pages/jsons/main.json', 'utf-8');
      let parseJSON = JSON.parse(openJSON);    and the code bellow the loop is what is written in my json file

Comment: Well, then that is invalid JSON. And you don't show how it gets into the `parseJSON` variable.

Comment: **Edit** the question to show a [mcve]

Comment: no, the json code is correct if you're saying about the {} in json files i din't put in question to save space, the parseJSON variable is = JSON.parse(openJSON); which openJSON is a fs module call that opens the json file.

Comment: @quentin i edited now is with a reproducible coode, i the entire function and the json

Comment: Why are you not using `require('./pages/jsons/main.json')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is obviously the loop. While the `sites` array in your JSON object from the `main.json` file only contains two entries, your loop makes four iterations. This means, that the JavaScript interpreter (keep in mind its interpreted at runtime) throws the error at the third loop where it cannot find any property `name` for the third element in the `sites` array as there simply is no third element (i.e. JSON object).

**Solution 1:**
You can limit the iterations of the loop to the `length` of the `sites` array by changing the condition of the `for` loop like this:

```
let main = []
let openJSON = fs.readFileSync('./main.json', 'utf-8');
let parseJSON = JSON.parse(openJSON);

for(let i = 0; i < parseJSON.sites.length; i++){ 
    main.push(parseJSON.sites[i]["name"]);
}
```

**Solution 2:**
If the number of iterations needs to stay at a fixed length (e.g. `4` like in your example), you can catch the error with a `try-catch` block. Check out the example below.

```
let main = []
let openJSON = fs.readFileSync('./main.json', 'utf-8');
let parseJSON = JSON.parse(openJSON);

for(let i = 0; i <= 4; i++){ 
    try {
      main.push(parseJSON.sites[i]["name"]);
    } catch (TypeError) {
      // handle TypeError
      console.log(`No property 'name' found for entry at index ${i}`)    
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:**
While the `try-catch` solution (i.e. Solution 2) is working, it may be too much for the given scenario as stated by [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201303/julian). Therefore, I have included the following solution that checks if the `sites` array at index `i` has an entry or is `undefined`. Note that I included two possibilities in this solution.

```
let main = []
let openJSON = fs.readFileSync('./main.json', 'utf-8');
let parseJSON = JSON.parse(openJSON);

for(let i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    // declare current entry (for readability)
    const currEntry = parseJSON.sites[i]

    // checking if there is an i-th entry in sites
    if (currEntry) {
      main.push(currEntry["name"]);
    }

    // same solution, more compact approach
    currEntry ? main.push(currEntry["name"]) : null
}
```

Comment: I think checking for `undefined` in your second solution is better than a try-catch

Comment: @Julian Yes you can also check for `undefined`. My second solution was just a quick example but there are multiple ways on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes there are multiple solutions. You could also do `while(2<3)` instead of `while(true)`. But not all solutions are nice. I think this is a really bad example for using a try-catch.

Comment: @Julian You are right. Using a `try-catch` block for this scenario is not the best approach. Therefore, I have added a third solution that checks for `undefined`. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks, I think it's important to **not** learn new ones to overuse try-catches (image the number `4` is `1000` ...). You got my upvote :)